# Multi argument pthread_create() function in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a task in which i have to pass more than one parameter to the thread calling function in C.
to be clear `pthread_create(&threadName, NULL, search_thread, parameter1)` is my thread creation, in which i want to pass more parameter for search_thread function. Is it possible?
basically i want `pthread_create(&threadName, NULL, search_thread, parameter1, parameter2,...)`

Answer (score 7):

The last parameter of `pthread_create()` is `void*`. You could always define a structure to encapsulate the multiple parameters, cast its address into `void*`, and cast it back inside `search_thread()`.

Comment: Pretty much clear Sir. Thank you @timrau